# How do you store calendar month and days in array?

Tags: c#

How would you store all 12 months and their correct amount of days in an array? Making a 12 by 31 array is two much for some of the months, like Feb has only 28 days. The rows would be the months and the columns would be the number of days.  Suggestions?

Comment: To store the amount of days (= one number per month) you need an `int numberOfDays[12]`, don't you?

Comment: Their *days* or their *correct amount of days* ? Because the latter would be a 12 entry array of `int`.

Comment: How do you want the array to be structured? (a) Monthly (b) Weekly?

Comment: I assume he wants to store some information per day - a kind of calendar or schedule.

Comment: row equal months, columns equal days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you want one value per day, rather than just the *number* of days for each array...

You could either use a rectangular array and ignore the "extra" days or use a jagged array:

```
GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
string[][] values = new string[12][];
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    values[i] = new string[calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, i + 1)];
}
```

Comment: Just curious: what's the difference to `DateTime.DaysInMonth()` (beside the better name ^^)?

Comment: @tanascius: I was browsing around and didn't spot DateTime.DaysInMonth. This route does make it explicit that it depends on which calendar you're interested in of course - but otherwise DateTime.DaysInMonth would be fine too.

Comment: side question, that doesnt actually put anything in values just creates the space for  it right?

Comment: @Jack: yes, it creates a 2 dimensional array of the exact size you need. Nothing is filled in. What values do you expect it to put in?

Answer (score 4):

[Jagged arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) are the standard solution to your problem. Instead of

```
T[,] foo = new T[12,31];
```

use

```
T[][] foo = new T[12][];

foo[0] = new T[31];
foo[1] = new T[28];
foo[2] = new T[31];
foo[3] = new T[30];
       ...
foo[11] = new T[31];
```